# How to read a `geography` column by `SqlDataReader`?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sqldatareader, geography, sqlgeography

I have a SQL Server 2008 database with a `geography` column which is generated by `System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography` in Entity Framework 6.0.0-alpha3.

Now I need to read that column with a `SqlDataReader`. But I have no idea how to do this. Using the old context is not an option. I tried to cast it as `DbGeography`:

```
Location = (DbGeography)reader.GetValue(index)
```

But I get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography'
>   to type 'System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography'

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it was simple. I was just confused. But instead of deleting the question, I'll post the answer to others who they have the same question.

```
// read the value as dynamic:
dynamic temp = reader.GetValue(index);

// the temp contains Lat and Long properties:
var text = string.Format("POINT({0:R} {1:R})", temp.Long, temp.Lat);

// the temp also contains the STSrid as coordinate system id:
var srid = temp.STSrid.Value;

// the rest is really simple:
Location = System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography.PointFromText(text, srid);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your geography is a point, you can use:

> SELECT MyColumn.Lat, MyColumn.Long ...

```
reader.GetDouble(0);
reader.GetDouble(1);
```